# What is Lower Traffic Area (LTA) airspace in France?

Tags: airspace, france

In France, [AIP ENR-2.1 subsection 2.1.2](https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/dvd/eAIP_26_APR_2018/FRANCE/AIRAC-2018-04-26/html/eAIP/FR-ENR-2.1-fr-FR.html#ENR-2.1) defines airspaces of type CTA (control area), UTA (upper traffic area) and LTA (lower traffic area).

I'm not familiar with LTA which appears not to exist outside of France and isn't part of [AIXM](http://aixm.aero) neither. Can anybody fill me in on how LTA differs from CTA and how it could be coded in AIXM?

Comment: "*LTA: FL 115 to 195, UTA: FL195 to 660*" ([Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espace_a%C3%A9rien)). Created in 1992, a LTA is a class-D CTA (E over Alpes and Pyrénées to allow VFR gliders) between and excluding other CTA (airways and TMA), and up to 12 NM of the shoreline. I've highlighted a class-E LTA nearby Perpignan TMA and the Spanish border on [this SIA map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sSrt.jpg). Synoptics of the [French airspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vP9l.png) ([source](http://www.kf2.free.fr/kf2/KF2-C03.pdf)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mins Has answered the question in his comment above:

> LTA: FL 115 to 195, UTA: FL195 to 660" ([Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espace_a%C3%A9rien)). Created in 1992, a LTA is a class-D CTA (E over Alpes and Pyrénées to allow VFR gliders) between and excluding other CTA (airways and TMA), and up to 12 NM of the shoreline. I've highlighted a class-E LTA nearby Perpignan TMA and the Spanish border on [this SIA map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sSrt.jpg). Synoptics of the [French airspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vP9l.png) ([source](http://www.kf2.free.fr/kf2/KF2-C03.pdf)).